# EF 6 Code First models - what is the parent virtual ICollection<child> reference for?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm following this [Building a simple ToDo application](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/20/building-a-simple-todo-application-with-asp-net-identity-and-associating-users-with-todoes.aspx?PageIndex=2#comments) which is an EF code first model.

This is slightly simplified code from the example that creates two tables, **MyUsers** and **ToDos**

```
public class MyUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual ICollection<ToDo> ToDoes { get; set; }
}

public class ToDo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool IsDone { get; set; }
    public virtual MyUser User { get; set; }
}
```

My question - what is the ICollection in the parent table for?

```
public virtual ICollection<ToDo> ToDoes { get; set; }
```

If you take this line out of the code you get the same two tables with the same referential integrity.  This is because the **ToDo** class contains a the reference to the parent

```
public virtual MyUser User { get; set; }
```

Either way it works, so why is it included?  Most examples of creating referential integrity include the same format.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without it you won't be able to navigate from a user to his Todo's easily.

Comment: Ah, yes of course!  I was so focused on the creation of the database tables and the referential integrity, I wasn't really thinking about accessing the objects from the code.  My objective was to create the database tables with the minimal lines of code, hence my question.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

With this `ICollection<ToDo>` you could load the `ToDo`s of a specified `MyUser` in one DB transaction, if you need. in the other word, you could load one (or more of cource) `MyUser` with its `ToDo`s during a single statement:

```
using(var context = new MyDbContext)
{
   var firstUserWithItsToDoes = context.MyUsers.Include(t => t.ToDoes).FirstOrDefault();
}
```